# Authorize directly after payment(Spring Boot + Paypal)

Tags: spring, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am currently using the PayPal API to process payments inside my application. My problem is the following: My application is now capable of creating an order and letting the user approve the order. What I want to accomplish is authorizing the amount the user approved to directly after the user approved the order. I know it is possible to authorize an order but from what I understand this is only possible after the user approved the Order. So what I want to know is the following: is it possible to let the user approve with the order and then authorize in one step, without the interfering of my backend(Spring Boot). Or should I let the frontend make a call after the user approved, so that another endpoint in my application can try the authorization of the funds. It al comes down to the fact that I don't know when to make the authorization call. What is the best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you want to create an order with `"intent": "authorize"` and then authorize it from your backend after approval (rather than capturing it, as would be the case for intent:capture).

For this you need to make two routes, one for 'create an order for authorization' and one for 'authorize an order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). The second one should (on success) store the resulting authorization ID, `purchase_units[0].payments.authorizations[0].id` ...for later capture

Pair these two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: You understand my situation. My application is coded in Spring Boot and I don't understand javascript but from what I understand I will have to wait for the frontend to let me know my order has been approved by the user.

Comment: Yes, that is what the above does and explains.

Comment: This is the last time I will ask a stupid question but I am very confused. On the authorisation vs capture page they first say an authorization places the funds on hold for 30 days. But then later on they say the following "Success of the capture is subject to risk and availability of funds on the authorized funding instrument." What is the point of placing the funds on hold if succes of the capture is not guaranteed?

Comment: 29 days is the window in which an authorization can be captured, but funds not held for that entire time. Generally the "honor period", as it is called, is 3 days. Capturing after that 3rd day is the same as attempting a new transaction, but you have the authorization to make this attempt without user interaction.  Capturing during during days 1-3 is still not a 100% guarantee since something can still prevent success, but will generally work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I fully understand that now. And can a user approve an order if they don't have the funds? I need to know this to estimate the changes of a succesfull authorization.

Comment: Their account needs to have funds or their credit card or other funding source needs to approve the authorization for it to be successful